# does anybody know where does "am start-activity --track-allocation" command save recent allocation?

Tags: android

In **am** command , there is   **start-activity** sub command ,and it has a  **--track-allocation: enable tracking of object allocations** options.

By looking the source code of ActivityManagerService and ActivityThread handleBindApplication function, I found it opened a recently allocation track. But I don't know when and where it saved tracing file. can anybody tell me ?

```
Activity manager (activity) commands:
  help
      Print this help text.
  start-activity [-D] [-N] [-W] [-P <FILE>] [--start-profiler <FILE>]
          [--sampling INTERVAL] [--streaming] [-R COUNT] [-S]
          [--track-allocation] [--user <USER_ID> | current] <INTENT>
      Start an Activity.  Options are:
      -D: enable debugging
      -N: enable native debugging
      -W: wait for launch to complete
      --start-profiler <FILE>: start profiler and send results to <FILE>
      --sampling INTERVAL: use sample profiling with INTERVAL microseconds
          between samples (use with --start-profiler)
      --streaming: stream the profiling output to the specified file
          (use with --start-profiler)
      -P <FILE>: like above, but profiling stops when app goes idle
      --attach-agent <agent>: attach the given agent before binding
      --attach-agent-bind <agent>: attach the given agent during binding
      -R: repeat the activity launch <COUNT> times.  Prior to each repeat,
          the top activity will be finished.
      -S: force stop the target app before starting the activity
      --track-allocation: enable tracking of object allocations
      --user <USER_ID> | current: Specify which user to run as; if not
          specified then run as the current user.
      --windowingMode <WINDOWING_MODE>: The windowing mode to launch the activity into.
      --activityType <ACTIVITY_TYPE>: The activity type to launch the activity as.
      --display <DISPLAY_ID>: The display to launch the activity into.
      --splashscreen-icon: Show the splash screen icon on launch.
```